# How do I maintain my v-model after JQuery replaces my DOM?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, anime.js

I'm trying to create motion graphics for OBS and I need to create it on something that can be changed on the fly. I usually work with After Effects/JavaScript, never with HTML/CSS.

I'm using Vue to do this, I tried stitching a few codes I find online, for the most part it worked great, however I am struggling to make Vue and JQuery work together.

I somewhat understand what the problem is:

```
$('#name').each(function(){                  
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});
```

This replaces my original DOM with new ones, and because of that I cannot change my text on the fly anymore. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to solve or go around this problem.

```
window.onload = () => {
    new Vue({
            el: '#vue-app',
            data: {
                name: 'Didier Drogba',
                subtitle: '@HelloWorld',
                transition_in: 1200,
                transition_out: 1100,
        },
        methods: {
            animate() {
                $('#name').each(function(){
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
                });

                anime.timeline({loop: true})
                  .add({
                    targets: '#name .letter',
                    translateX: [40,0],
                    translateZ: 0,
                    opacity: [0,1],
                    easing: "easeOutExpo",
                    duration: this.transition_in,
                    delay: function(el, i) {
                      return 500 + 30 * i;
                    }
                  }).add({
                    targets: '#name .letter',
                    translateX: [0,-30],
                    opacity: [1,0],
                    easing: "easeInExpo",
                    duration: this.transition_out,
                    delay: function(el, i) {
                      return 100 + 30 * i;
                    }
                  });               
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I expect the output is that my text is fully animated and I can adjust it on the fly.

Thank you.

Comment: Vue uses a virtual DOM and this can have challenges for jquery.  For what you are trying to do, I would use a VueJS computed function which could return the text in your 'name' value using the replace function you are wanting to do.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: These two animals are not meant to live together, for exactly the reason you describe.